# How get the latest value in pick list

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to develop an extension/pipeline task for Azure DevOps for release gates. Not getting how to bind the the latest value to the pick list as shown here:

[image]

Each time a build completes, pick list should have latest build Id as the selected value.

Here is the code snippet i tried,
This creates a pick list

```
{
  "name": "buildId",
  "type": "pickList",
  "label": "Artifact",
  "required": true,
  "defaultValue": "Latest",
  "properties": {
    "DisableManageLink": "True",
    "EditableOptions": "True"
  }
  "helpMarkDown": "Build Artifacts"
},
```

this binds the values for the picklist

```
{
  "target": "buildId",
  "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
  "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/{{system.teamProject}}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0",
  "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
  "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{buildNumber}}} \" }"
}
```

Let me know if there are any way to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I afraid you will need to implement your own code methods to bind `latest` value to the latest buildid.

For example in [Publish build artifacts task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DownloadBuildArtifactsV0). The latest build id is retrieved according to the selected value(ie. latest) of field `buildVersionToDownload`: See below:

[image]

`buildVersionToDownload` has three options.

```
  {
                "name": "buildVersionToDownload",
                "type": "pickList",
                "label": "Build version to download",
                "defaultValue": "latest",
                "visibleRule": "buildType == specific",
                "required": true,
                "options": {
                    "latest": "Latest",
                    "latestFromBranch": "Latest from specific branch and specified Build Tags",
                    "specific": "Specific version"
                }
            }
```

If the `buildVersionToDownload` value is selected as `specific`. Then it is required to select the build id in the `Build` picklist.

```
{
            "name": "buildId",
            "type": "pickList",
            "label": "Build",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "visibleRule": "buildType == specific && buildVersionToDownload == specific",
            "properties": {
                "EditableOptions": "True",
                "DisableManageLink": "True"
            },
            "helpMarkDown": "The build from which to download the artifacts"
        }
```

`buildVersionToDownload` is not bound to dataSource, only `buildId` is bound:

```
{
            "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
            "target": "buildId",
            "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/{{project}}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={{definition}}&resultFilter=succeeded,partiallySucceeded&$top=200",
            "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
            "parameters": {
                "project": "$(project)",
                "definition": "$(definition)"
            },
            "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{buildNumber}}}\" }"
        }
```

See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DownloadBuildArtifactsV0/task.json) for more information.

If `buildVersionToDownload` is selected as `latest`. Then the latest build id is retrieved via code. See code example [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DownloadBuildArtifactsV0/main.ts#L171-L192)

So that in your custom task. When the `Default Version` is `latest`. You can get the latest build id in your code methods. And when `Default Version` is not  `latest`. Then make the `Artifact` visible to select a build id from the picklist.